# Low contrast urban style

Tags: post-processing, color

I love the colors and the tone of this [photo](https://500px.com/photo/117653427/untitled-by-visualsbypierre). How can I achieve this look with camera raw and/or photoshop?

[image]
Image of [VisualsByPierre](https://500px.com/visualsbypierre)

Comment: Please read [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/4262)

Comment: See also: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Histogram. See how the blacks aren't at the far left; that means the contrast was reduced / flattened.

If you inspect the photo further you can find the darkest portion has a distribution of RGB as 11, 39, 42. If you create a Curve you can confirm this by setting this point as Black and seeing how the image probably looked closer to out of camera (other than the terrible job dodging her back):

[image]

So if we keep that in mind and take any relatively ungraded image we can set the black point to the same value and it'll be pretty close. The rest will be tweaking based on the exact characteristics of the photo. Here's a somewhat ungraded looking photo via Unsplash - https://unsplash.com/photos/U22pJ6BclUQ

[image]

Now because this guy has lighter skin and there's no big yellow taxi in the background, or much yellow at all. We might want to choose a different color palette but this is what your example is.

I might look at the colors and think, blue is probably the weakest choice for this so drop it down and let the reds and greens be the more prominent ones:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing.

This image has inconsistent shadowing. There are shadows from the sun, but back side of girl is lightened as well.

So either someone had used extra light source like delicate flash or reflecting plates.

Or image has extra lightening in Photoshop or similar software. I would guess it is more probable as on the border of the jeans shirt and the yellow car there is also not natural lightening.